# How to change ::before SVG background-image color on hover, focus, active

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the SVG background-image in ::before element: https://codepen.io/sshiling/pen/PVWgdW 
I want to change it's color on hover, focus, active. I try to use this method: 
:hover::before path {
    fill: #000;
} 
 
But it doesn't work 
[image]

I can just duplicate my inline SVG and change it's color manually, but maybe there is a way to change it with "path fill" or something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
   <div class="field__search"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.field {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #849d8f;
}

.field__search {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 66px;
    position: relative;
}

.field__search::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16.687' height='16.688' viewBox='0 0 16.687 16.688'><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #fff;fill-rule: evenodd;}</style></defs><path id='Лупа' class='cls-1' d='M931.155,40.747H930.4l-0.264-.261a6.212,6.212,0,1,0-.675.675l0.263,0.262v0.755l4.773,4.76,1.423-1.422Zm-5.731,0a4.291,4.291,0,1,1,4.3-4.291A4.294,4.294,0,0,1,925.424,40.747Z' transform='translate(-919.219 -30.25)'/></svg>");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.field__search:hover::before path,
.field__search:focus::before path,
.field__search:active::before path {
    fill: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using SVG's data URI as a background image, meaning that its properties and styles cannot be modified—the SVG markup is not part of the DOM and therefore untouchable with CSS. It is akin to referencing a `.svg` image path in your `background-image` property.

The only solution is—as you have suspected—to simply encode a brand new SVG for the hover state:

```css
.field {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #849d8f;
}

.field__search {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 66px;
  position: relative;
}

.field__search::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16.687' height='16.688' viewBox='0 0 16.687 16.688'><path class='cls-1' d='M931.155,40.747H930.4l-0.264-.261a6.212,6.212,0,1,0-.675.675l0.263,0.262v0.755l4.773,4.76,1.423-1.422Zm-5.731,0a4.291,4.291,0,1,1,4.3-4.291A4.294,4.294,0,0,1,925.424,40.747Z' transform='translate(-919.219 -30.25)' fill='#fff' /></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.field__search:hover::before,
.field__search:focus::before,
.field__search:active::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16.687' height='16.688' viewBox='0 0 16.687 16.688'><path class='cls-1' d='M931.155,40.747H930.4l-0.264-.261a6.212,6.212,0,1,0-.675.675l0.263,0.262v0.755l4.773,4.76,1.423-1.422Zm-5.731,0a4.291,4.291,0,1,1,4.3-4.291A4.294,4.294,0,0,1,925.424,40.747Z' transform='translate(-919.219 -30.25)' fill='#000' /></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="field__search"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution will require changes to your markup, where you actually embed the SVG in an image map, and utilise the `<use>` element to reference the symbol. However, this means that you will be injected unnecessary empty elements in your markup for the sake of stylistic/visual purposes, a practise that may be frowned upon by some:

```css
.field {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #849d8f;
}

.field__search {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 66px;
  position: relative;
}

.field__search__icon {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  fill: #fff;
}

.field__search:hover .field__search__icon,
.field__search:focus .field__search__icon,
.field__search:active .field__search__icon {
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Symbol map -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 0; height: 0; visibility: none;">
  <symbol id="my-custom-icon" width='16.687' height='16.688' viewBox='0 0 16.687 16.688'><path d='M931.155,40.747H930.4l-0.264-.261a6.212,6.212,0,1,0-.675.675l0.263,0.262v0.755l4.773,4.76,1.423-1.422Zm-5.731,0a4.291,4.291,0,1,1,4.3-4.291A4.294,4.294,0,0,1,925.424,40.747Z' transform='translate(-919.219 -30.25)' /></symbol>
</svg>

<div class="field">
  <div class="field__search">
    <svg class="field__search__icon">
      <use xlink:href="#my-custom-icon" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```